# Substantial Differences Between Cordova 3.8 and 4.0?

Tags: cordova, telerik-appbuilder

I am having trouble upgrading from 3.8 to 4.0, but if there are substantial differences as far as performance or reliability then I'll know it's worth it.  Can someone inform me how different the two versions are?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of Telerik AppBuilder, "Cordova 4.0" really means:

- Cordova-Android 4.0.2
- Cordova-iOS 3.8.0
- Cordova-WP8 3.8.0

So the important piece is really the changes in Android and the biggest of those is the ability to use an alternative webview called Crosswalk. I'll let [this blog post](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/telerik-appbuilder-with-cordova-4-and-crosswalk-support) do the rest of the explanation :).